# Oracle db logger into Spring Boot application.properties file

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I use oracle DB in Spring Boot project. I want to set error logger for the database in Spring console. This configuration must be made in application.properties file I think. (This code example shows another oracle db properties). How can I do that?

```
oracledb.url = <oracle_url>
oracledb.user =  <oracle_user>
oracledb.password =  <oracle_password>
oracledb.poolname= <oracle_poolname>
```

Comment: I believe you are headed in the wrong direction here. what you have above looks like you are preparing the connection for a connection pool. Depending on what driver you use for JDBC you will need to decide how you are going to log for your application in general. Look at LOG4j and implement that I and than you can capture errors and info depending on your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```